# Compiz burn effect gone in 12.10?

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiz Problems (Plugin Missing, Performance Issues, Development)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215462/compiz-problems-plugin-missing-performance-issues-development)

It's a small thing, but I like it when windows burst into flames when I close them. I've been using this effect in compiz for ages in Gnome Ultimate (aka Gnome Classic).

After installing 12.10, not only has this effect seemingly been disabled, it seems that the extra animations and effects that support it aren't even available. In Synaptic, there is a "transitional dummy package" for extra animations, but installing it does nothing.

Can I get back my beloved flame effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated my answer (And the title of the question) here:
[Compiz Problems (Plugin Missing, Performance Issues, Development)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215462/compiz-plugin-missing-cube-reflection-cube-deformation-fire)

To cover all plugins missing from Compiz and reason for them. Please feel free to read them there.

Answer (score 2):

There's a thread on [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068636) about this:

"*This has been discussed before, Sam was the last and only compiz developer, and was thinking of stopping development of compiz completely, until he was hired by Canonical, all the other developers had quit, and moved on to other projects, so effectively it's a one man show. It seems seeing as no other distributions use compiz, there aren't a lot of people stepping up to the plate to help with the plugins.*"

I too am sad to see this option gone.

Comment: Actually there are 100+ members related to the Compiz team, of which, 13 are direct ones. Of this 13 all of them are still active, working on either Compiz 0.9.9, Compiz 0.9.8.8 or both.