# How to install compiz-plugin-extras and make it work correctly?

Tags: 13.04, compiz, 32-bit

I'm still having problems with Compiz...

I did everything that you imagine... but "animation add-on" still does not appear in Compiz...

I have already done the command `apt-get install compiz-plugins-extras` and `compiz-plugins*` to install all plugins but Compiz still does not show the "Animation add-on"...

What can I do?

I know this is not a big problem, but in any part of internet, people say how to enable the"Animation add-on" they but already know this.

I want to know how to get a "complete" install of Compiz with all plugins.

Please post step by step. (If I have to add new repository, if I have to move paste, if I have to download and extract and install the plugin)... Step by step....

I think it will help a lot of people who still have this question.

Comment: As of 12.10, some compiz plugins are not available anymore. Please see [Compiz Problems (Plugin Missing, Performance Issues, Development)](http://askubuntu.com/q/215462/65926).

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:
[Compiz Experimental](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/install-compiz-experimental-plugins-in.html)

It always work for me, i am on Ubuntu 14.04.
[image]

Comment: I'll say that I followed that link and the important tip that it gave me was to press `Alt-F2` then run `compiz --replace`...I already had everything installed but it just wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same as you did before I found out that the packages compiz-plugins-extra and the experimental ones are just transitional dummy packages. These have been available for 12.04 and were dropped in 12.10 and up. It's pretty said, I loved them as well. So the only way I can think of is to get the deb-package from 12.04's repos and extract the files to their respective directory (I do not know if this works; never tried it) or downgrade to 12.04.

Comment: so you're telling me that this problem has no solution?... but there is videos on youtube... of people did it work...

Comment: The most important... i'm using UBUNTU 13.04

Comment: The cube will work but the additional add-on will not here is a bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1069112

Comment: So Add-on will not work... thx!!.. but on youtube and in other forums there is people saying that is possible install the "Animation Add-on"...

Comment: I have found something regarding experimental plugins for Compiz, but I haven't used them in Raring, only Precise. You might wanna take a look at this page [link](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Compiz+Experimental+Plugins+U%2BD+3-18-12?content=118511)

Answer (score 0):

always go to this website if you are unable to find what you want on the software center

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/compiz-plugins-extra

go to the download section and press on the all arch deb package ... this works for 14.04 i'm pretty sure it will work for you cheers have a great day