# Compiz burn effect in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, compiz, effects

I have a problem with Compiz. I installed Compiz setting manager on Ubuntu 13.04, Also installed Compiz main and extra fusion plug-ins. But I can't enable 3D windows and cube reflection effects and burn effects . The check boxes of these plug-ins doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/205734/169736

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "Animation add-on" option:

- Open Compiz setting manager
- Check Animation add-on checkbox
- open animation ... and do as suggested

Comment: I have enable Animation add-on but not working Because I don't have burn effects , Some say burn effects  do not only exist in ubuntu 12.04 but 13.04 Non-existent !!

Answer (score 0):

These are the only packages you need to run compiz with animation effects on 13.04:

```
apt-get install compiz compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-default compizconfig-settings-manager dconf-tools
```

All other packages compiz-plugins-extra etc. are just placeholders in 13.04 (empty packages they created to maintain compatibility), see my list of installed packages (some descriptions in italian)

```
compiz - window manager e compositing manager OpenGL
compiz-core - window manager e compositing manager OpenGL
compiz-dev - window manager e compositing manager  OpenGL - file di sviluppo
compiz-gnome - window manager e compositing manager OpenGL - decoratore di finestre GNOME
compiz-plugins-default - window manager e compositing manager OpenGL - plugin predefiniti
compiz-plugins-main-dev - transitional dummy package.
compiz-plugins-extra - transitional dummy package.
compiz-plugins-main - transitional dummy package.
compiz-plugins-main-default - transitional dummy package.
compizconfig-backend-gconf - transitional dummy package.
compizconfig-settings-manager - Compiz configuration settings manager
compiz-plugins - OpenGL window and compositing manager - plugins
```

You might have a configuration issue preventing from using the effects, there is a complete profile and apt-get scripts available for download here: http://www.istitutomajorana.it/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2154&Itemid=33  (direct download link: http://www.istitutomajorana.it/scarica2/Compiz-Effetti_3D_Ubuntu_13-04.tar.gz) it worked for me.

The result: I have 3d desktop (both cubic and spheric effects), I can paint fire on the screen, but haven't been able to use it as a Windows Close effect, seems to be an effect of this migration of plugins from sub-packages. Also 3d-windows appears to be broken. But you'll still get a great looking desktop!